# Detox fails with "Cannot find module 'jest-cli/build/cli/args'"

Tags: jestjs, detox

Our CI builds began failing recently with an error like this:

```
detox test -c android.emu.release
detox[3061] ERROR: [cli.js] Error:
Cannot find module 'jest-cli/build/cli/args'
```

Locally `detox test -c android.emu.release` succeeds. Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

**UPD: ⚠️⚠️⚠️ The workaround below is NOT needed for the recent Detox versions [since 17.5.2](https://github.com/wix/Detox/releases/tag/17.5.2) and newer. ⚠️⚠️⚠️**

*For the versions between 17.4.7 and 17.5.1, the following text is historically valid.*

If you are seeing an error like the one below:

```
Cannot find module 'jest-cli/build/cli/args'
```

You should add `jest-cli` to your `package.json`'s `devDependencies` and re-run `npm install`, e.g.:

```
 "devDependencies": {
   "jest": "26.x.x",
+  "jest-cli": "26.x.x",
```

If you are using a deprecated version of `jest` (25.x), still make sure that your `jest-cli` version **matches** `jest`'s one:

```
 "devDependencies": {
   "jest": "^25.5.4",
+  "jest-cli": "^25.5.4",
```

P. S. Regarding why it is happening. While `detox@17.4.7` was not meant to contain any breaking changes, this issue has slipped past the testing lifecycle due to another installation method (via `lerna bootstrap` instead of the vanilla `npm install`). Unlike `lerna`, the current versions of `npm` would put `jest-cli` into `node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli`, that's why Detox is unable to find one, although `detox` package itself has `jest-cli` package in the manifest marked as *peerDependency*, and the relevant warnings are printed:

```
npm WARN detox@17.4.7 requires a peer of jest-cli@>=25.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```